# Integrate $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^2+1}{(x+1)^2(x+2)}$

Tags: integration

$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^2+1}{(x+1)^2(x+2)}$

= $ \frac{A}{(x+1)} + \frac{B}{(x+1)^2}+ \frac{C}{(x+2)} $

= $A(x+1)(x+2) + B(x+2) + C(x+1)^2 = (A+C)x^2 + (3A + B + 2C)x + (2A + 2B + C)$

= $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
3 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
2 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$
RREF 
= $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & -4 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 5 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Thus we have:

$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{-4}{(x+1)} + \frac{2}{(x+1)^2} + \frac{5}{(x+2)}$

= $-4\ln(x+1) - \frac{2}{(x+1)} + 5\ln(x+2) \bigg]_{0}^{1}$

= $-4\ln(2) - 1 + 5\ln(3) + 4\ln(1) + 2 - 5\ln(2)$

= $ 5\ln(3) - 4\ln(2) - 5\ln(2) + 1$

However, it is nowhere near the book's answer, which is $\frac{1}{2} - 5\ln(2) + 3\ln(3)$.

I think I might have messed up on the integration after solving the system of equations, but I don't see any obvious mistakes (it just feels the weakest for me there), but I am able to differentiate everything back into an integral...

Comment: $ 5\ln(3) - 9\ln(2) + 1$ is the right one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^2+1}{(x+1)^2(x+2)}= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{-4}{(x+1)} + \frac{2}{(x+1)^2} + \frac{5}{(x+2)}$
>
> = $ 5\ln(3) - 4\ln(2) - 5\ln(2) + 1 \approx \color{blue}{0.2547}$

You are [correct](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1%20(1%2Bx%5E2)%2F((x%2B2)(x%2B1)%5E2)%20dx) and the book isn't; well done!

> However, it is nowhere near the book's answer, which is $\frac{1}{2} - 5\ln(2) + 3\ln(3) \approx \color{red}{0.33}$.

---

To compare with WolframAlpha's answer, rewrite:
$$5\ln(3) - 4\ln(2) - 5\ln(2) + 1 = 1-\ln\left(\frac{2^5 \cdot 2^4}{3^5}\right)= 1-\ln\left(\frac{512}{243}\right) \approx 0.2547$$

Comment: wow! okay then :D

Comment: It's normal to doubt your own calculations when the manual's answer is different, but the manual isn't always right... :-). You can easily verify answers like this with [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) - great tool!